# Necessary to delete computer account from AD before rejoining to the domain?

Tags: active-directory, domain

What is actually stored within the computer account in AD?  There always seems to be issues that crop up once and awhile where leaving and rejoining the domain seems to fix them.  Up to this point i've been removing from the domain, deleting the computer account in AD, and then rejoining.

Is deleting the computer account in AD necessary?

Answer (score 1):

No, resetting the computer account should accomplish the same end result.

Comment: Forgot about that....

Answer (score 0):

Is isn't strictly *necessary*, because the actual process of leaving the domain - if done properly - should remove the computer account anyway, as long as the user moving the computer from the domain to a workgroup has the correct privileges.

Note that if you have a complex AD schema, your permissions may be associated with specific OUs, rather than global permissions across the whole schema - for example you may only be authorised to remove computer accounts within a specific OU.

That being said, if the issue is that the computer/domain trust has been broken, you may need to manually remove the account from AD, or as Greg has said, simply reset the computer's account.